# I have been facing this XCode error? Any fixes?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func declareName() {
        print("hello")
    }

declareName() //I get an error here saying :
```

}

> Expected '{' in body of function declaration

**I was working on something complex and it wasn't working. So i tried the very basics and I got this error. Any fixes?**

Comment: Is that your whole file? If yes, it's missing a closing } (the one corresponding to `class ViewController: UIViewController {`

Comment: Where is declareName being called from? Did you close the ViewController class with a closing bracket?

Comment: You can't call a function at the class level scope, it has to be done from inside another function

Comment: sorry guys. I did have the closing bracket. I just didn't add it here.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson what the hell. So u can never call a function right after writing a code for it. For example : 
                                                                                        
func add (a: Int) {
 print(a)
}

add(5)   

Is this wrong?

Comment: @PSJ You won't get far by swearing. Edit your comment to remove the bad language before it's too late.

Comment: Mind your language please. No, a call like that will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

All executable code must live in a function body. Therefore, in answer to your comment, yes, this code is illegal:

```
func add (a: Int) { print(a) } 
add(5)
```

You would have to say:

```
func add (a: Int) { print(a) } 
func callAdd() { add(5) }
```

Comment: Same way. It's an infinite regress. :) Seems like your code can never get started, eh? But fortunately, in real life, sooner or later some runtime event will call into your code, such as `viewDidLoad`, a button tap `IBAction`, etc., and your code will start to run in that function. iOS Cocoa programming is _event-driven_. See my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_functions

Comment: I think I just did. If my answer was right and helped you, the correct response is not to say "wow" but to accept it.

Comment: Apple's bookstore has two Swift books. One for the language, one mostly for interfacing with other languages.